# Entity framework - select specific columns

Tags: c#, web-services, entity-framework

this is my user model or class

```
 public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string UserPassword { get; set; }
        public int CompanyID { get; set; }
        public int BranchID { get; set; }
        public bool RecordState { get; set; }


        public virtual Branch Branch { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
```

and this is my company class

```
public int CompanyID { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string CompanyShortName { get; set; }
        public string CompanyAddress { get; set; }
        public string CompanyPhone { get; set; }
        public string CompanyEmail { get; set; }
        public string CompanyFax { get; set; }
        public bool RecordState { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Branch> Branches { get;  set; }
        public virtual List<Customer> Customers { get;  set; }
        public virtual List<Market> Markets { get;  set; }
        public virtual List<Seller> Sellers { get;  set; }
        public virtual List<User> Users { get;  set; }
```

this my [WebMethod]

```
 public User getUser(int id)
        {
            User user = db.Users
                .Include(c => c.Company)
                .Where(i => i.UserID == id)
                .FirstOrDefault<User>();

            Company company = db.Companies
                .Where(i => i.CompanyID == user.CompanyID )
                .FirstOrDefault<Company>();

            company.Branches = null;
            company.Customers = null;
            company.Markets = null;
            company.Sellers = null;
            company.Branches = null;
            company.Users = null;

            user.Company = company;

            return user;
        }
```

My method is long beacuse I want to avoid circular reference but I think my steps is not good and it takes many steps I want to know i there any why that I can get the company inside user with one query and it should also return an object type user because ? i'm really sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is the first and the last line of that method.  The rest is completely redundant.  By specifying the Include path you are already getting the company, so there's no need to get that separately.  By not specifying any other include paths, you are already not getting any more related records, so setting all those properties to null is pointless.

Comment: When I just use the first line I got this error System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the XML document. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type GraduateServer.Models.User.

Comment: You probably need to turn lazy loading off in your EF context.  As suggested in another comment, EF is designed for lazy loading, which means that related entities will be retrieved when accessed.  When passing objects from a web service though, you know exactly what related entities you need up front so you should turn lazy loading off and use Include calls to be explicit about what related records to retrieve.  After creating your DbContext, do this: `context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;`

Comment: Fisrt it's off, second would please write a simple code what I want is when I looking after user by ID I want Include company but I don't wanna get all the columns of Company I wanna choose what I want, sorry for my bad english

Comment: I don't know what to tell you.  That exact type of thing works for me.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232#explicit I followed and I write this var user = db.Users;            db.Entry(user).Reference("Company").Load(); but still nothing work

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to do *way* too much. I'm pretty sure your code won't actually do what you want. This is all you need. (I'm assuming that `db` is a property or field that's already been instantiated in your class.)

```
public User getUser(int id)
{
    return db.Users.Find(id);
}
```

Once you return the User, you can get the company like this

```
var user = getUser(25);
var userCompany = user.Company;
```

Comment: I want to get the related object in this case I meant company in ur case company is null

Comment: If company is null then you need to set it and persist the changes to the database.

Comment: I think that because that u don't set Include this method gave u the related object

Comment: `Include` is only needed for eager loading. Entity Framework is *designed* for lazy loading, which is the way that we're doing it here.

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the XML document. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type GraduateServer.Models.User.

Comment: You may want to try creating a new object to return that contains just the properties you need. Serializing the User entity is likely to cause that issue.